# Find JMX Server URL using JConsole

Tags: java, jmx

I'm having problems programmatically connecting to a local JMX server. I doubled checked the JMX server and it seems to fine, but I'm still unable to connect.

However, using JConsole, I have no problems.

Is there anyway to find the correct server URL from JConsole?

By the way, here is the server I'm trying to connect to:

```
String jmxServer = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:" + DEFAULT_PORT + "/jmxrmi";
```

And these are the JVM options I'm launching my process with:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=DEFAULT_PORT
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you and print out the system property

`com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress`

which should give you the local connector address.

then from your client something like

```
final JMXServiceURL jmxURL = new JMXServiceURL(localConnectorAddress);
final JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxURL);
final MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

should do it... (well does do it, as i done it)